# NGINX failed to pass traffic to application

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx proxy in front of an application (listens 10.10.10.10:80) that a SSL certificate is terminated, but have an issue when trying to access the log-in page, as nginx redirects traffic to port 80 (which doesn't listen).

The NGINX configuration is shown below:

```
server {
    listen 10.11.11.11:443 ssl;
    server_name test.example.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/test-access.log main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/test-error.log warn;

    client_body_buffer_size 1M;
    client_max_body_size 16M;
    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    send_timeout 10;

    ssl_certificate        <PATH>/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    <PATH>/cert.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;



location / {
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_ignore_headers   Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header Content-Type;
    proxy_pass_header Content-Disposition;
    proxy_pass_header Content-Length;
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_send_timeout 90;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    proxy_buffers 32 4k;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_force_ranges on;
    }
```

}

what is needed in order NGINX redirects traffic always to 10.11.11.11:443 and apparently to 10.10.10.10:80?

PS If I manually enter the FQDN (https://test.example.com) to the failed request, then request becomes successful.

hope I explained it properly :)

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are testing using the IP Address (10.11.11.11) and your proxy_pass endpoint (10.10.10.10) is configured to only accept requests for specified FQDN (test.example.com) on HTTP (TCP port 80).

When it receives a request for a domain it does not recognize it redirects the user to what it believes should work http://test.example.com

You have a couple options to fix this

1. Update the upstream server to accept requests for additional host header values
2. Rewrite the 302 location header in the response to change the protocol from HTTP to HTTPS
3. Configure server block to listen on HTTP and have it redirect to HTTPS
4. Hard code the 'proxy_set_header Host' directive to test.example.com so it matches what the upstream expects (Not recommended because it could create unexpected results down the road when troubleshooting different issues)

Comment: can you provide more info for 1. ?  how will I configure it for additional host header values?

Comment: depends on the platform/software the upstream is running.

If it is nginx, you can add an additional server_name directive inside of the server block